# Qt Installer Framework : Hide the Back button

Tags: qt, installation, qt-installer

How to Hide the Back Button in Qt installer framework?

Please see attached image.

[image]

Comment: This is my code :

function Controller()
{
 if(installer.isUninstaller){
  wizard()->button(QWizard::BackButton)->setEnabled(false);
 }

}

Comment: This code should disable button, does it work for you?

Comment: What about `setVisible(false)` ? Because disabling is not hiding ..

Comment: @Aaron I tried the setVisible(false) but its not working.

Comment: Yes as there are options like `QWizard::NoBackButtonOnStartPage` I guess whatever you try to do with the button will be overruled.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to [Qt installer framework hide or disable buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58068014/7400441) quoted below:

> For the wizard BackButton specifically, it automatically disables itself if there are no pages before the current page a la the Introduction page.
>
> From QtScript this can be accomplished by removing any dynamic pages  before the current page with `installer.removeWizardPage` and disabling all default pages before the current page with `installer.setDefaultPageVisible(QInstaller.Introduction, false)`.

Comment: Any tips on how to get rid of the entire lower panel? All buttons.

Answer (score 0):

There is `void QWizard::setButton ( WizardButton which, QAbstractButton * button )` what means you schould be able to set a button which behaves like you need it. Derive a Class from QAbstractButton. Reimplement the `paintEvent()` to paint nothing and reimplement the `mouseEvents` to do nothing. That should do the (dirty) trick. Even if the wizard sets it to be visible, it won't draw itself and can't digest and mouse actions. Just tested it ... should work for you.

Comment: Still failing using the code below.

function Controller()
{
   setOption( QWizard::NoBackButtonOnLastPage, true );

}

Comment: Using the approach above should result in an invisible back button all the time. What is the problem with the last page ?

Comment: I want to hide the back button in the last page(for uninstall only).

Comment: May be you can work around that be calling the `setButton()` function with your invisible button when the last page appears. You could use the `showEvent()` of that last widget.

Comment: Your idea seems to be applicable to `QWizard` in C++ but I don't see how to do this on the Qt Installer Framework context, where the only thing we have is a control script (javascript). I must be missing something, isn't?