# Qt installer framework hide or disable buttons

Tags: qt, qt-installer

I want to hide or freeze the back button on a page ( to be more specific, License Agreement Page). I tried editing control.qs with few methods but it doesn't seem to work. Following is one of them

```
Controller.prototype.LicenseAgreementPageCallback = function()
{
    var widget = gui.currentPageWidget();
    if (widget != null) 
    {
        widget.BackButton.setVisible(false) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to know too! If it's really not possible, a workaround could be to auto-click next on the page before (based on some condition).

Comment: Thank for the idea. But I want it so that user cannot go back after that page. I will comment if I found a way to do that.

Comment: Where can I find documentation for things like `widget.BackButton.setVisible(false) ;`? Specially the `setVisible` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm facing a similar problem trying to keep hide the `Next` button in the `Target Directory` page under certain conditions.

But your case may be easier:

1) You should use a global `boolean` variable set to `true` when you enter the `License Agreement` page.

2) When you enter the previous page test the value of this global: if `true` then force a click on the next page (`gui.click(buttons.NextButton);`).

Yes, it's a dirty workaround ;)

Comment: Did you managed to hide the `Next` button? I wondering how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try what I've proposed here: [Qt installer framework: remove radio buttons from uninstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27290010/qt-installer-framework-remove-radio-buttons-from-uninstaller/33170889#33170889). Even if it wasn't accepted, that what I used in my installer, so I'm pretty confident it's working!

Answer (score 0):

For the wizard BackButton specifically, it automatically disables itself if there are no pages before the current page a la the Introduction page.

From QtScript this can be accomplished by removing any dynamic pages  before the current page with [`installer.removeWizardPage`](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/scripting-installer.html#removeWizardPage-method) and disabling all default pages before the current page with [`installer.setDefaultPageVisible(QInstaller.Introduction, false)`](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/scripting-installer.html#setDefaultPageVisible-method).

Comment: Do you have any sugestion on how to hide the `Next` or `Quit` buttons?